# How can I impute the standard deviation for mean difference from p value?

Tags: meta-analysis, network-meta-analysis

I am doing meta-analysis comparing two groups. I came across a paper that provided the pre and post means with the standard deviation for three groups without providing the mean difference and its SD for each group. How can I impute the SD for the mean difference in two groups from a p-value of ANOVA test? The p values for the post hoc tests were not provided.

Comment: The paper provided the Bonferroni-adjusted paired samples t-test for the difference between the pre and post measurements in each group.

Comment: If you are comparing two groups, why are you wanting the standard deviation of the differences rather than the raw standard deviation? In computing a Cohen' d (or Hedges' g) type effect size comparing two groups, the typical standardization is the pooled within groups standard deviation. Taking into account a pre-test such that the numerator is a difference in differences doesn't change this, although an argument can be made for pooling the pre-test standard deviations. Standardizing on the standard deviation of differences has a very different and complicated meaning.

Comment: What do you mean by two groups -  pre and post measurement  for each of three groupings ?